# Pass a listener to a method that creates View with this listener issue

Tags: android, listener, mvp

this is my situation:
I want to pass a listener to a view generator for using it. but the problem is in my listener I want to use that View to get some data. some how twisted...
is that a way to pre-define a View like a interface that Listener should attach to?

```
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {

               //but I can not do this and use spinner cause it is not defined
                String text = spinner.getSelectedStrings().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {}
        };

generateSpinner(attributes, listener);
```

I'm working on MVC project in android and this issue come out from there, cause I should separate creation and Logic to View and Presenter. So my presenter force view to generate a spinner with given logic.

Comment: Using this sample repository you can learn more about MVP mixture with dagger: http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel

Comment: @MohsenMirhoseiniArgi thanks a lot I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

You have answered more than half of your question yourself. Make an interface like this:

```
public interface MyViewCallback
{  
    void run(View view); 
}
```

Now, you can store a instance of this `interface` and call its `run()` method from your `View`'s scope whenever you need to - for example,

```
MyViewCallback callback;

// ... on some action
callback.run(this);
```

You can create a setter for this `callback` and use it to register a callback.